# DB Connections Logs if any issue while communicating with DB after successful connection in prestashop 1.6

Tags: database, prestashop-1.6, mysql-error-1064, error-logging

I want to log the errors if there is an issue in communication with the database after successful connectivity in PS 1.6. So anyone can suggest how I can do that?

**If I'll use MySQL Cluster and my DB connection is established successfully but there is some issue in MySQL Cluster and My Website is down so how I can get the logs for it?**

Answer (score 0):

If Prestashop cannot connect to DB , a return code error 500 will be raised on all websites pages, so you can rely to an uptime check service and see if website is reachable.

If you want to check the DB connectivity alone, just put together a shell script that check the connection to the cluster at regular intervals, or a PHP script that tries the database connection the Prestashop way with **Db::getInstance()**  and trigger some alert if DB is down.